CAC reader on Ubuntu
I recently got a System-76 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to get a CAC reader to work following the absolutely lovely walkthrough posted by M-Pepper here: https://github.com/M-Pepper/linux-cac-walkthrough.
I cannot get opensc to register in firefox, using pkcs11-register or manually. When I use the pkcs11-register command, it shows that it added OpenSC to ~/.pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt, but when I go into firefox and check security devices (settings > Privacy & Security > Security Devices), there is no OpenSC; the only thing that shows up is NSS default devices and OS devices.
When I try to add a security device manually through that same menu, I get an alert saying Unable to add module.
I initially installed OpenSC from apt, but then I removed it and built from source so I'm running 0.25, on firefox 129.0.
I alternatively tried a setup script from another source that used Cackey, but that also failed and I ultimately removed Cackey and its associated packages.
I'm not sure where to go from here... please help!

as well, modutil -l ... shows OpenSC 0.25 in the nssdb

The snap version of Firefox doesn't work this way.
Uninstall it (sudo snap remove firefox), and then follow these instructions on AskUbuntu to install the .deb package.
